# Using pouchdb-adapter-memory plugin in vue3

Tags: node.js, typescript, vuejs3, pouchdb

I am trying to start a local PouchDB database with a memory adapter mode using the package `pouchdb-adapter-memory` on a `vue3` project.
After installing the package, I am getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: inherits3 is not a function`

When starting the vue app without the package and running PouchDB normally it dose work.
Also, when trying to run PouchDB on a local server (not on the frontend) in memory mode, it dose work.

Here is an example of the usage of the package:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDBFind from 'pouchdb-find';
import PouchdbAdapterMemory from 'pouchdb-adapter-memory';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
PouchDB.plugin(PouchdbAdapterMemory);

class LocalDBClass {
    private localDB: PouchDB.Database;

    public async init(dbName: string){
        this.localDB = new PouchDB(dbName, { adapter: 'memory' });
    }
}
```

Here is a list of steps I was trying to use in order to solve the issue:

1. I was trying to delete the `node_modules` directory and reinstall the packages using `npm i`.
2. I was trying to look for other ways to implement it, but all of the other solutions are using the package `pouchdb-adapter-memory` in one way or another.
3. I was trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886246/bundling-pouchdb-adapter-memory-with-rollup) solution with no success.
4. I was trying to achieve my goal by using the package [pouchdb-memory](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-memory) with no success.
5. The only way I did make it work, was by import it in the `index.html` (see the block of code below). It is not a good solution, because I am consuming PouchDB from an external package that I've created.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@8.0.1/dist/pouchdb.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@8.0.1/dist/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
 </head>
...
```